# Best way to create "custom URI" intents in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have heard that using your own URI scheme a) can cause namespace clashes and b) other people can create apps which intercept the same URI schemes.

As such instead of employing a URI scheme such as `myapp://whatever` you should use intent uris (starting with I presume `intent://`).

Now of course searching for "intent://" on google turns up lots of info on `intent`s but none on the uri scheme/interception thing.

If anyone can shed some light on this I will be very grateful. Specifically the case is that I want to create an app which will contact an OAuth api and don't want others to be able to create apps which can "intercept" the same uri scheme as I invoke. e.g. anyone could write an android app which responds to `myapp://something` but apparently they can't if I use the `intent://` method.

Many thanks